# IMSSP "Tried to bind parameter number 0" error when binding array values in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, foreach

I have a PHP associative array, the values of which I want to bind with PDO in a foreach loop. So far I have this:

```
$sqlSecondaryInsert = "INSERT INTO TCMS_Documents ";

// Table Fields
$sqlSecondaryFields = " (DocumentID, ";
$sqlSecondaryValues = "VALUES (:lastDocumentInsertID, ";

foreach ($intersectArray as $key => $value) {
    if (trim($value) != '') {
        $sqlSecondaryFields.= trim($key) . ", ";
        $sqlSecondaryValues.= ":" . trim($key) . ", ";
    }
}

$sqlSecondaryFields = rtrim($sqlSecondaryFields, ", ");
$sqlSecondaryFields.= ") ";

$sqlSecondaryValues = rtrim($sqlSecondaryValues, ", ");
$sqlSecondaryValues.= ")";

$sqlSecondaryStmt = $sqlSecondaryInsert . $sqlSecondaryFields;

$stmt2 = $connPDO->prepare($sqlSecondaryStmt);

$stmt2->bindValue(':lastDocumentInsertID', $lastDocumentInsertID);

foreach ($intersectArray as $key => $value) {
    error_log("attempting to bind " . $key . " to value " . $value);
    $stmt2->bindValue(':' . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$stmt2->execute();
```

While the SQL INSERT statement is being generated correctly, I receive the following in my PHP error log when trying to execute it:

```
"IMSSP",-29,"Tried to bind parameter number 0.  SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters."
```

The PHP log is showing the correct keys and values from the error_log within the foreach loop, so I don't understand why the PDO bindValues are not working.

An example `print_r` of `$intersectArray` can be seen here:

```
[DocumentNumber] => 123
[ValidFromDate] => 02/09/2015
[ValidExpiryDate] => 26/09/2015
```

**Edit**: Some additional information that may or may not be useful: we are using SQL Server 2008. I don't know if this is relevant, I have no understanding of how the PDO drivers differ for SQLSRV and MySQL...

Comment: Is `DocumentID` the same as `DocumentNumber`?

Comment: No, DocumentID is the $lastDocumentInsertID value.

Comment: FWIW, `implode()` is often much better than custom loops that do similar kind of things.

Comment: @Smar, I'm glad you like my answer. Maybe give an upvote instead of repeating it in the comments :P

Comment: @Adelphia: I was going through review list, that tool does not show answers along the post.

Comment: Anyway, now when I read the question a bit more closely, I guess the real problem is that the array just contains far too many parameters (over 2100) so fails because of that. This would be good place for http://www.sscce.org/ ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Here's an [example](https://3v4l.org/MKF7s).

```
function generateInsert($table, $data){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (".implode(", ", $data).") VALUES (:".implode(", :", array_keys($data)).")";
    $exe = array();
    foreach($data as $k=>$v) { 
      $exe[":$k"] = $v;
    }
    return array("sql"=>$sql, "exe"=>$exe);
}

$q = generateInsert("TCMS_Documents", $intersectArray);

$sql = $q['sql'];
$exe = $q['exe'];
$stmt = $connPDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($exe);
```

Make sure you add your `lastDocumentInsertID` column to the `$intersectArray` array though.

Comment: Nice one, that works marvelously! I had to edit it slightly to make it work on my Windows/SQLSRV/PHP stack but thanks for all your help! Wish I could upvote you but I don't have a high enough reputation yet.

Comment: Oh, yeah the backticks are a MySQL thing :P Glad to have helped though :)

Comment: I see there was a mistake in the part that generates the `$exe` variable as well. I fixed it but you probably already noticed that.

Comment: Oop yeah, just edited it again to reflect that! Cheers.

Comment: You have no idea how pleased I am that this finally works, thanks again!